# PerformanceCounter throws exception

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I have to get the System Up time using some sort of techniques. Suggested by someone in StackOverflow I have used Performance Counter to get the System Up time in TimeSpan.

```
            try
            {
                var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
                uptime.NextValue();
                return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
```

It's perfectly run on my PC without any problem. But problem occurs in my friend's computer. On his PC, while running the following line throws exception.

```
var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
```

Exception was `"Input String was not in Correct format"`.

Comment: No, PerformanceCounter doesn't raise a FormatException.  Consider deleting the try/catch keywords.

Comment: @HansPassant, I also believed until I found this exception, I tried deleting try/catch, my application freezes and it says, "Not Responding"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PerformanceCounter` can behave differently depending on permissions etc. - for some information regarding this see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx).

Another point is that in Windows XP some performance counters are not available if no paging file is configured (for details see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884558/en-us).

Something unrelated:

"Swallowing" exceptions like you do with an empty `catch` block is BAD practice!

Comment: I have tried more than 6 computers parallely, only that friend's computer throws this weird exception, i don't know why.

Comment: yes...I have followed the links and it says all about permission. I think, my friends PC don't have the essential permission for the code...

Comment: @jchoudhury if the permissions are not set correctly then the code won't work... correct the permissions and try again... BTW: please upvote/mark as accepted any answers that are of help (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: how do you think about using Environment.TickCount() instead of Performance Counter

Comment: @jchoudhury it can give you wrong values since it is a 32 bit integer which mean that it wraps back to 0 after 24.9 days of uptime (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx).